# Найти значения x, y, для которых выражение в системе счисления будет наименьшим и кратно 56

Tags: python, системы-счисления

Операнды арифметического выражения записаны в системах счисления с основаниями 15 и 16:

90x4y_***15*** + 91xy2_***16***

В записи чисел переменными x и y обозначены допустимые в данных системах счисления неизвестные цифры. Определите значения x и y, при которых значение данного арифметического выражения будет наименьшим и кратно 56. Для найденных значений x и y вычислите частное от деления значения арифметического выражения на 56 и укажите его в ответе в десятичной системе счисления.

Сам вопрос - что делать, если системы счисления будут большими? Там, 72, 123 и так далее? Как в таком случае написать код? Допустим, для выражения найти минимальное частное при делении нацело на 40:
88x4y_**123** + 7x44y_**72**

```py
result_search = []
for x in '0123456789ABCDE':
    for y in '0123456789ABCDE':
        t = int('90' + x + '4' + y, 15) + int('91' + x + y + '2', 16)
        if t % 56 == 0:
            result_search.append(t)
if result_search:         
    print(min(result_search) // 56)
```

Хотелось бы идею попроще и удобнее. спасибо

Comment: в случае систем с большим основанием вопрос скорее в способе записи цифр... как, например, записать цифру "120" в 123 СЧ ? и этот вопрос, скорее, к проверяющему / заказчику

Comment: Идея попроще: привести всё к десятичной системе и не думать как записать цифру 120 в 123 системе. Вы задаче этого не требуется.

Answer (score 0):

```py
m =[]
for x in range(15):
    for y in range(15):
        v = 9*15**4 + x*15**2 + 4*15 + y + 9*16**4 + 1*16**3 + x*16**2 + y*16 + 2
        if v%56==0:
            print(x,y, v//56)
            m.append(v//56)
print(min(m))
```

Указывать минимальную систему счисления?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите

Comment: Ну да, похоже. Разве что в `if` можно сразу добавить `break` потому что дальше перебирать `y` не имеет смысла. Ну и в целом можно ещё пооптимизировать, но уже не принципиально.